# Innodb or MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

This post is not about any issues or coding problem rather an effort to know or to choose which kind of storage engine should I choose depending on what kind of system I am building.

Before posting my question here I was going through several blogs/posts to know the difference between the two and I have gained some knowledge.

I am making a questionnaire system where the users can answer to hundreds of question and those answers will be archived for future use.

In a thread I came to know that MyISAM is faster for reads, InnoDB is faster for writes.

My question is, can I keep the main db storage engine as Innodb and mix the db table types with myIsam/Innodb.

Is that recommended?

Comment: The top answer to that question is pretty good. These days Inno is default, and there will generally be no discernible performance difference. Do you need full text search?

Comment: That was my first link after research.

Comment: I am not sure if I need full text search as it is not included in the scope of work yet but might be in future.

Comment: The basic answer is you may as well use inno exclusively unless you need full text search for a specific table.

Comment: Thanks @bcmcfc that's all I wanted to know.